# 1C 8.3 (Обычные формы). С помощью какой функции можно сделать оповещение всем пользователям?

Tags: 1с

1C 8.3 (Обычные формы). С помощью какой функции можно сделать оповещение всем пользователям в режиме реального времени?

Например, поступает товар в заказе покупателя. Все активные пользователи получают оповещение, что поступил новый заказ.